# Multiple possibilities for FIELDS TERMINATED BY - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a .csv file to mysql using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

In the.csv file, fields are separated by space but in a certain field there are multiple information separated by `,` (comma).

I would like to also parse that field.

How to add multiple possibilities space or comma for `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` in mysql?

A sample single row of the .csv file I am working with is provided:

```
1565067700.891 0 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TCP_DENIED/403 0 CONNECT tunnel://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ - NONE/- - BLOCK_ADMIN_CONNECT_12-DefaultGroup-DefaultGroup-NONE-NONE-NONE-NONE-NONE <-,-,-,"-",-,4,-,-,"-",-,6.5,-,"-",-,1,"-","-",-,1,-,-,"-","-","low","-","-","-",0.00,0,-,"-","-",-,"-",-,-,"-","-",-,-,"-",-> - "06/Aug/2019:11:01:40
```

I would like to parse the content between < > in the above line along with rest of the fields those are separated by space

So far I have tried:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE `mytable` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@col1, @col2, @col3) 
set id=@col1, name=@col2, company=@col3;
```

Comment: add `ENCLOSED BY '"'` next to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`. then let us know.

Comment: tried but not worked.  All the contents inside < > are not enclosed by ' " ' @James

Comment: Can you help me on separating, like which contents should come in col1, col2, col3...

Comment: Currently i am using workbench to load the csv, for me it is working fine. btw before i import in excel i tried "text to column" and it separates the data in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider pre-processing the file to replace the commas with spaces so that you can use LOAD DATA without any further tweaking. Since it doesn't *appear* that commas are expected in any of the data, this could be as simple as `tr -s ',' ' ' < file.csv > processed.csv` on linux. Similarly, you could replace all spaces with commas i.e. `tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' < file.csv > processed.csv` and then set `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`.

Comment: thanks a lot. In my case replacing all spaces with commas works, but replacing all commas with spaces doesn't work and showed the error: tr: when translating, the only character classes that may appear in
string2 are 'upper' and 'lower'

Comment: My mistake, I'll update the answer to correct that. Thanks for noticing!